# Asp.Net VB webform How to export a template field Gridview to csv?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, export-to-csv

I have a gridview where all its fields are TemplateField which contain textboxes as its ItemTemplate. The idea of the application is for the gridview to get a template from the database via an SqlDataSource. Then the user may edit the desired gridview rows via the textboxes and press a button to convert the gridview to a csv file.

I resulted to this method do to my understanding that the edit and update gridview controls updates the database values and I do not want to alter the database records.

**My Code**

I have tried using this method but from my understanding it only works with BoundFields and not Templatefields because it returns blank values when using Templatefields.

```
Sub ExcelConvertion2()
    Response.Clear()
    Response.Buffer = True
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.csv")
    Response.Charset = ""
    Response.ContentType = "application/text"

    Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()

    For Each cell As TableCell In GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells
        'Append data with separator.
        sb.Append(cell.Text & ",")
    Next

    'Append new line character.
    sb.Append(vbCr & vbLf)

    For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows

        For Each cell As TableCell In row.Cells
            'Append data with separator.
            sb.Append(cell.Text & ",")
        Next

        'Append new line character.
        sb.Append(vbCr & vbLf)
    Next

    Response.Output.Write(sb.ToString())
    Response.Flush()
    Response.End()
End Sub
```

**Gridview code**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#336666" BorderStyle="Double" BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="4" Font-Size="Small">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Handle">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="HandleTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Handle") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TittleTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="BodyHTML">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="BodyHTMLTextBox" runat="server"  Text='<%# Eval("BodyHTML") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Vendor">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="VendorTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Vendor") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Type">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TypeTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TYPE") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Tags">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TagsTextBox" runat="server"  Text='<%# Eval("Tags") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#336666" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#336666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#339966" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#487575" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E5E5E5" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#275353" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

Example of a tempate:

[image]

**Question**

How can I convert the TemplateField gridview to a csv file.

Comment: If you can use javascipt, you can do it with a function using `getElementsByTagName("tr")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method that you have above but you need to specifically get the values of each textbox.

```
Dim txtType as Textbox
Dim txtVendor as Textbox


 For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows

      txtType = CType(row.FindControl("TypeTextBox"), TextBox)
      txtVendor = CType(row.FindControl("VendorTextBox"), TextBox)

       sb.Append(txtType.Text & ",")
       sb.Append(txtVendor.Text & ",")

        'Append new line character.
        sb.Append(vbCr & vbLf)

    Next
```

Comment: tried to implement your method but when I execute the program again i got the error: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

`For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
            handle = CType(row.FindControl("Handle"), TextBox)
            title = CType(row.FindControl("Title"), TextBox)
            bodyHTML = CType(row.FindControl("BodyHTML"), TextBox)

            sb.Append(handle.Text & ",")
            sb.Append(title.Text & ",")
            sb.Append(bodyHTML.Text & ",")
            sb.Append(vbCr & vbLf)
        Next`

Comment: Make sure that the value you have in quotes in the row,FindControl matches the ID value of your textbox. For example, I don't see a textbox control with an ID of "Handle" in your sample codeblock, but I do see a textbox with an id= "HandleTextBox"